# VBA script to concatenate a cell value based on two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and just now started to automate things in excel. I have a requirement to concatenate a cell value based on two columns. For example

[image]

In the above excel, in the A column if Doc2 exists thrice, but it has levels of 3,4 & 3 (in row number 3,4, &6 respectively). I want to concatenate values of the id into a single column like below

[image]

Based on level and Document Name, if both are same then concatenate id else do not.

```
Sub ConcatenateCellsIfSameValueExists()
DestRowRef = 2
CheckedCell = Cells(2, "A").Value
For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If Cells(i, "A").Value <> CheckedCell Then
        tempConValues = tempConValues
        Cells(DestRowRef, "C").Value = tempConValues
        tempConValues = ""
        DestRowRef = DestRowRef + 1
    End If
    tempConValues = tempConValues & " " & Cells(i, "B").Value
    CheckedCell = Cells(i, "A").Value
Next
End Sub
```

I tried the above code, it only concatenates based on single-cell and also, repeated Document name once concatenated is not deleted. Can anyone please help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA I would use a Dictionary to organize the data.
For a key, concatenate what you want to group (DocumentName and Level) and for the contents the concatenated ID's.

```
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Option Explicit
Sub jugate()
'Declare variables
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim D As Dictionary
    Dim I As Long, V As Variant
    Dim sKey As String
    
'set Source and Result worksheets and ranges
Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet4") 'edit to real worksheet
Set wsRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet4") 'could put this on different sheet
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 6)
    
'read table into array for fastest processing
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=3)
End With

'read into dictionary, combining like doc/level
Set D = New Dictionary
    D.CompareMode = TextCompare
    
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc) 'skip header row
    sKey = vSrc(I, 1) & "|" & vSrc(I, 3)
    If Not D.Exists(sKey) Then
        D.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=vSrc(I, 2)
    Else
        D(sKey) = D(sKey) & vbLf & vSrc(I, 2)
    End If
Next I

'create results array
ReDim vRes(0 To D.Count, 1 To 3)

'header row
For I = 1 To 3
    vRes(0, I) = vSrc(1, I)
Next I

'populate data
I = 0
For Each V In D.Keys
    I = I + 1
    vRes(I, 1) = Split(V, "|")(0) 'doc name
    vRes(I, 2) = D(V) 'concatenated ID
    vRes(I, 3) = Split(V, "|")(1) 'level
Next V

'write results to worksheet
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes

'Next lines are just for formatting
'not really necessary and not internationally aware
    .Style = "output"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

You can also obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps
- After Close/Load, format the resultant table for Word Wrap and centering.

  - This formatting should persist through subsequent refreshes.

**M Code**

```
let

//Change table name in next line to your actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"DocumentName", type text}, {"ID", type text}, {"Level", Int64.Type}}),

//group by doc name and Level
//then aggregate the text strings
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"DocumentName", "Level"}, {
        {"ID", each List.Accumulate([ID],"",
            (state,current)=> if state = "" then current else state & "#(lf)" & current), Text.Type}
        }),

//Place columns in desired order
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"DocumentName", "ID", "Level"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer and it works like charm. I have some more changes to be done, but I want to try on my own before asking a query, thanks a lot for this solution